# How to select and crop an image in android?

Tags: java, android, image, android-intent, crop

Hey, I am currently working on a live wallpaper and I allow the user to select an image which will go behind my effects.

Currently I have:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            i.putExtra("crop", "true");
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

And slightly under that:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (requestCode == 1)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
          Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
          Log.d("IMAGE SEL", "" + selectedImage);
          // TODO Do something with the select image URI
          SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("imagePref", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
          Log.d("HO", "" + selectedImage);
          editor.putString("imagePref", getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage));
          Log.d("IMAGE SEL", getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage));
          editor.commit();
        } 
    }
```

When my code is ran, Logcat tells me that selectedImage is null. If I comment out the

```
i.putExtra("crop", "true"):
```

Logcat does not give me the null pointer exception, and I am able to do what I want with the image. So, what is the problem here? Does any one have any idea how I can fix this? Thanks, for your time.

Comment: I have the same question, 
and this thread helps, 
 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238460/android-2-1-crop-image-fail

Comment: another similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758425/how-to-set-the-output-image-use-com-android-camera-action-crop/

Answer (score 47):

I have also faced this problem .You can try with this code. Its working fine for me

```
private static final String TEMP_PHOTO_FILE = "temporary_holder.jpg";  

Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);

private Uri getTempUri() {
    return Uri.fromFile(getTempFile());
}

private File getTempFile() {

    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),TEMP_PHOTO_FILE);
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {}

        return file;
    } else {

        return null;
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
                if (imageReturnedIntent!=null) {

                    File tempFile = getTempFile();

                    String filePath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        +"/"+TEMP_PHOTO_FILE;
                    System.out.println("path "+filePath);


                    Bitmap selectedImage =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                    _image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                    _image.setImageBitmap(selectedImage );

                    if (tempFile.exists()) tempFile.delete();
                }
            }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Just remember if you want to delete files you'll probably need to add this permission to your manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: @Haraldo. I did'nt check it in android 4.1. I will check and update

Comment: @jennifer What about to do same for Camera Capture as well any idea ?

Comment: Intent getCameraImage = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

Comment: i can find path using your code...but i cant show image

Answer (score 7):

You don't need a Temp file:

```
protected static final int REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE = 1;



Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
                    if (imageReturnedIntent!=null) {
                        Bundle extras = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();
                        Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
                        imageR = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                        imageR.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
                    }
                }
        }       
}
```

Comment: You saved my day! On 4.3- - worked fine. on 4.4+ can use usual variant:
imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageuri);
Bitmap bmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

Comment: This is not working when selected Google Photos App to choose image

Comment: Null pointer exception comes when selecting photos from  Google photos app .

Comment: Nothing happens after selecting, cropping and clicking ok/check icon. It is stuck on the crop screen. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This code good with "beginners" ^^

```
private Bitmap FixBitmap;
Bitmap thePicBitmap;
String ImagePath = "image_path";
String ImagePath_1;
private static final String TEMP_PHOTO_FILE = "temporary_holder.jpg";
private static final int REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE = 0;




@Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {




            //intent = new Intent();
            // intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
             Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
             photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
             photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
             photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
             photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
             photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
             // indicate output X and Y
             photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", 150);
             photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", 100);


             photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
             photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
             startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);




            } catch (Exception e) {
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.imageException, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Upload_image_text.this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }




        }

        private Uri getTempUri() {
            return Uri.fromFile(getTempFile());
            }

        private File getTempFile() {
            if (isSDCARDMounted()) {

            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),TEMP_PHOTO_FILE);
            try {
            f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
            return f;
            } else {
            return null;
            }
            }

        private boolean isSDCARDMounted(){
            String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (status.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            return true;
            return false;
            }
    });
```

=======================

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);


    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
          if (imageReturnedIntent!=null){



          //     File tempFile = getTempFile();

              ImagePath_1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/temporary_holder.jpg";
              System.out.println("path "+ImagePath_1);


              FixBitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImagePath_1);
              ShowSelectedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
              ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);



          }
        }
    }
}
```

===============================

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 1;
            //options.outWidth = 50;
            //options.outHeight = 50;
            FixBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImagePath_1, options);
            //FixBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.imageView);

           byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           FixBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream); //compress to 50% of original image quality
           byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

           ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```