# Android 2.1 Crop Image Fail

Tags: android, crop

I followed this page to crop image on SDcard [How to select and crop an image in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085003/how-to-select-and-crop-an-image-in-android)

i placed the cropped image in **/data/data/package.name/files**, code works fine on Android 2.2 and above but when i ran this code on Android 2.1, after selecting the region i want and click "Save" and i always got "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION" error.

Why and what is that error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want like this:-

[How to Select and Crop Image on Android?](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/)

Download Sample:- https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidImageCrop

Only three changes required for android 2.1:-

1. In main.xml -> write wrap_content instead of matchparent.
2. In AndroidManifest.xml ->  `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />`
3. In default.properties -> `target=android-7`

Best of luck.