# Crop image functionality minimum SDK - Android

Tags: android, image, crop

i want to take an image from the SDCard, crop it, and get the cropped image to and imageview.

Looking for it in this site i found this code
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337988/1458576
and it seems to works fine (Using the android's built-in gallery).

I test this code in ICS (CyanogenMod 9), and the crop function uses the face detection.

Can anyone tell me what's the android's minimum-sdk version to use this function?
Or better way to do the "take/crop/get image"?

It's compatible with 2.1??

***EDIT***   AUTO-ANSWERED

It works fine (Tested) on: - SGS GT-i9000 Default rom (2.2) - SGS GT-i9000 CM7 and CM9 -SG3 GT-i5800 Default stock rom (2.2) and CM7.

It works using the default "gallery" or other installed via Market like QuickPik.

I published an app using this code and have no error (+5k downloads).

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you what is the minimum SDK for this code, but I found a nice code in GitHub for crop the images without use the Android Gallery app, that probably will give you problems on some devices

https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

Comment: I preffer to use the built-in gallery, if it's possible.