# How to crop the screenshot in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to draw lines in my app. After it is done, i want to save the screen as an image. But i don't want the button to be in the image. I want to crop it and then save it. I have tried to use this code to crop my bitmap in onclicklistener. But it didn't work.
Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 5, 5, 5, 5); 
this is my all code:

```
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 
    content.buildDrawingCache(); 
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(content.getDrawingCache()); // Bitmap
    Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 5, 5, 5, 5);
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    File file = new File("/sdcard/SurucuImza.jpg");
    FileOutputStream ostream = null;



    try {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            file.createNewFile();
            ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream); 
            ostream.flush();
            ostream.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = null;
    ostream = null;
    content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2085003/1007273

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the result of this line to a variable:

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 5, 5, 5, 5);

//Ex:
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 5, 5, 5, 5);
```

and then save the `croppedBitmap` instead of `bitmap.`

One more thing, are you sure your button is 5x5 pixel? The last two parameters of `createBitmap()` specifies the `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the variable size of Android screens sizes and densities I would suggest you to NOT use the `content`, but on your XML layout you have a `ViewGroup` that will be "printscreenable" and the other area (outside the viewgroup) with the button.

That way you'll have to do the same operation but using the `viewGroup` instead of the `content`