# android how to crop image

Tags: android

I need a code that allows to select the part of the image that I will crop with dragable triangle that selects the part of the image to be cropped. I mean the code is like that when I want to choose my profile picture in Viber or Facebook Application. Is there any code that is made for this case?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085003/how-to-select-and-crop-an-image-in-android

Comment: Have you any idea how to limit width and height of cropping ?
I mean that width/height is constant value. when width is 10 height = 20
and if width = 15 the height will become 30 automatically. width/height = 1 / 2