# No data returned after trying to retrieve and crop an image

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Im using the gallery view for the user to select an image. When the user has selected an image, he will be passed to the "cropping page". (This is not a custom activity as i've done)

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true"); 
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

When I return to onActivityResult my data is null and I cant retreive the cropped image.

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding intent extra

```
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

See example on:

http://nullpointerblog.com/2012/06/17/android-photo-chooser-with-crop/

Comment: Why does this only return a picture sized 160 x 160?

Comment: @Sebastian no clue, isn't it size of cropped area?

Comment: No, it is not! Doesn't matter what picture i choose or how big my cropped area is! Strange..

Comment: @Sebastian it is strange, but not an issue of this QA thread I'd say

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
private static final String TEMP_PHOTO_FILE = "temporary_holder.jpg";  

Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);

private Uri getTempUri() {
   return Uri.fromFile(getTempFile());
}

private File getTempFile() {

  if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),TEMP_PHOTO_FILE);
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    return file;
 } else {

    return null;
  }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
    Intent imageReturnedIntent) {

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
            if (imageReturnedIntent!=null) {

                File tempFile = getTempFile();

                String filePath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    +"/"+TEMP_PHOTO_FILE;
                System.out.println("path "+filePath);


                Bitmap selectedImage =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                _image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                _image.setImageBitmap(selectedImage );

                if (tempFile.exists()) tempFile.delete();
            }
        }
   }       
}
```

**Add Permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337988/1218762)