# com.android.camera.action.CROP The auto resize?

Tags: android, bitmap, crop

I using `com.android.camera.action.CROP`.
My code is very similar to [jennifer's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085003/how-to-select-and-crop-an-image-in-android)
My app works fine on Android 4.4 - 5.0, but there are some problems on API levels 4.0 - 4.3.

My question: 
For the latter, a cropped and saved image is smaller in size like illustrated [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/176fh.jpg).
Is there a known issue for `com.android.camera.action.CROP` in terms of auto resizing on some API levels?

Comment: "My error is the problem of com.android.camera.action.CROP" -- since [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html), I would argue yes. "is there any solution?" -- use [an image cropping library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45).